# How to handle multiple objects in variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare members is a list with the following script:

```
    $Guid = "59041b96-c71d-436c-8297-7af5fcf4e22a"

$Members = Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy -identity $guid -DistributionDetail | Select -ExpandProperty OneDriveLocation | select name,displayname | sort displayname 

$User = "Humbert, Jason"

    $ODPolicy = $members.displayname | Select-String -Pattern "Humbert, Jason"


    if($User -like $ODPolicy){
        Write-host "USer $($USer.primarysmtpaddress) is in"
        #$OD.RetentionSet = $True
        }Else{
        Write-Warning "User $($USer.primarysmtpaddress) not in Policy"}
```

The output for $ODPolicy returns 2 names because there are two mailboxes (Active, and inactive)

PS C:\Users\XYZ> $ODPolicy

Humbert, Jason
Humbert, Jason

When running the `if($User -like $ODPolicy)` the script doesn't seem to be able to handle that there are two objects that are returned and it returns the `Else{ Write-Warning "User $($USer.primarysmtpaddress) not in Policy"}`

How can I modify this so that the `if($User -like $ODPolicy)` sees it as true and returns the `Write-host "USer $($USer.primarysmtpaddress)` is in"?

Comment: ```if ($members.displayname -contains  "Humbert, Jason"){}```is enough

Comment: Thanks, that simplified it for me.

Comment: @Toni Could you please provide your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-like` operator is not useful here because you want an exact match and you want to verify if a collection of items `$members` contains a specific single item `$User`.

So you should switch to the `-contains` operator, e.g.:

```
if ($members.displayname -contains  "Humbert, Jason"){}
```